# Rejoining threads in C

Tags: c, pthreads

In my main function, I spawn j threads which all compute the same task in parallel -- and then I want to wait for them to finish before exiting.

```
int main(...) {

    // ...

    int threads = 6;
    pthread_t* thread = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*threads);

    for(i = 0; i < threads; i++) {

        struct thread_param *tp;
        tp = malloc(sizeof(*tp));

        // ... 

        int ret = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &control, (void*)tp);

        if(ret != 0) {
            printf ("Create pthread error!\n");
            exit (1);
        }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < threads; j++) {
        printf("JOINING THREAD: %i\n", j);
        pthread_join( &thread[j], NULL);
    }        

    exit(0);
}
```

However, nothing waits. Main just exits without ever completing the threaded tasks. Am I missing something?

Comment: Since you've not shown us the function `control()`, it is hard to know whether it just returns immediately - so no waiting is required - or whether there is something else amiss.  You don't need the address-of operator in front of the thread function name.

Comment: That looks fine. What do you mean by "nothing waits"?

Comment: Without the & I seem to get a `Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.` error. It won't return immediately -- it does some FTP client interactions and then comes back. None of the print statements that are within control get executed, for example. Nor do they return with the file that I sent them out to fetch.

Comment: Both @Andrey and @paxdiablo have uncovered the joining problem. I guess I just can't figure out why it's segfaulting now.

Comment: I'd replace `control` with a function that returns immediately and see if that avoids the segfault. If so then I'd look harder at `control`.

Comment: Good suggestion. It does not segfault with `control()` simply returning 0. `Control()` itself threads yet another function (`data()` .. this is an FTP client), so perhaps this has something to do with it. I'll have to do some digging.

Comment: Just to follow up, I've isolated the problem to a function not even remotely related to my pthreads. Thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey, try `pthread_join( thread[j], NULL);` i think the problem is with types. I checked docs:

`int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **value_ptr);`

and `thread` is `p_thread*`, and `thread[j]` is `p_thread`, while `&thread[j]` is `p_thread*`, which is invalid. There just might internal error happen.

**Edit**: Yeah, I am very positive with that, `pthread_t` is basically `int`, so `pthread_t*` is accepted, it is just invalid thread handle, so `pthread_join` fails internally.

Comment: You're right. That does make everything wait, but for some reason it gives me a null pointer exception when it hits that line.